# CSS Image Rollover

Tags: css

I have script that handles image rollovers with css. What I would like to know if this the proper way of doing a CSS rollover? I also wanted to know if this is good how do you handle other rollover images do you have to have a separate css for each image?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/GFec3/40/

**CSS Code:**

```
a.rollover {
   display: block;
   width: 27px;
   height: 25px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background: url("http://www.gdisinc.com/barker/images/menubar/bnt_facebook.jpg");
}

a.rollover:hover {
   background-position: -350px 0;
}

.displace {
   position: absolute;
   left: -5000px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <a href="#" class="rollover" title="Webvamp" width="54" height="25"><span class="displace">TEST</span></a>
```

This works but just wanted to know is there a special way to handle more then one rollover image?

Comment: Removed CSS3 tag, since that tag should only be used when the question is specifically about CSS3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use background images in css. Example:

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
.roll .on { display: none; }
.roll .off { display: block; }
.roll:hover .on { display: block; }
.roll:hover .off { display: none; }
</STYLE>
<DIV class="roll">
  <IMG class="on" src="...">
  <IMG class="off" src="...">
</DIV>
```

There's lots of ways of doing this. Which to choose is up to you.

Comment: I'm looking for sort of a turn key way. The script I posted seems like a lot of work for every rollover. I would rather have a css script and then be able to an an off and on image and let css handle the swapping of them.

Comment: @FrankG. That's pretty much exactly what my example does. Use those classes anyplace you need a rollover.

Comment: I've been playing around with the script in jfiddle which you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/GFec3/48/ How ever the facebook link seem to flicker. The rest do work fine. Any suggestions? Also is the way to get all three images to show horizontal? Thanks again!

Comment: The facebook one flickers because you wrote `dsrc` instead of `src`. To make them horizontal change `block` to `inline` in the css (in both places). And instead of using a `DIV` with `roll` use a `SPAN`. You'll probably have to make two sets of css rules - one for `inline` one for `block`.

Comment: This is a cool solution! I felt it noteworthy to point out that if `DIV` is a link and you add a third image for the active state, the link won't click. No solution for this as of yet though.

Comment: @Brendan I don't get what you mean. Can you show me your code on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @Ariel http://jsfiddle.net/m9fxw5md/ - Clicking on the 'button' doesn't take you to the link.

Comment: @Brendan This is VERY interesting! It's caused by very subtle behavior. What's happening is you are clicking on the `hover` image, but your are releasing the click on the `press` image. So no proper click is generated to either image (which would trickle down to the `A`).

Comment: @Brendan You can make it work by either forgoing the press image, or try this version: http://jsfiddle.net/m9fxw5md/1/ which doesn't hide the image, instead it just makes it invisible.

Comment: @Ariel Ah! great solution. Thanks for taking the time to explore it!

Answer (score 2):

Use [**CSS sprite**](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), with this you will use only one background image, you just have to change background position for different image hover

[**CSS Sprites: Image Slicing’s Kiss of Death**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/)

Comment: Yea, I'm aware of that but don't like that whole idea because I would have to create a separate css entry for every rollover. Seems like to much more.

Answer (score 1):

The method you currently have is the most efficient. Among other things, it "preloads" the rollover image since it's the same one as the non-rollover just a different part of it. It also reduces the number of HTTP requests to the bare minimum (short of the `data` scheme) and in some cases actually improves filesize (best case is two images using similar colour palettes, one colour table needed instead of two).

Don't change it, it's perfect.

You do have to define a separate CSS for each rollover, however if the images are the same size you can reduce the damage by reusing the `:hover` definitions.

Comment: I don't see it because the image is just doubled as a spite which doesn't really save on file size. However you know XYZ Double your css file because if you have like 5 or 10 that's 5 or 10 entries in to your css that you wouldn't have to do! Thanks for the info!!